# Dont scroll the body when mouse is over child element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to stop my main page from scrolling when the user hits the bottom of two specific sections of a page using the following code, but it's stopping the mouse wheel from working over those divs at all.

```
 var scroller = document.querySelector('#Filters');

    scroller.addEventListener('wheel', listener);

function listener(event)
    {
        var elem = event.currentTarget;

        if ((event.deltaY < 0 && elem.scrollTop === 0) ||
            (event.deltaY > 0 && elem.offsetHeight + elem.scrollTop >= elem.scrollHeight))
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else if ((event.deltaX < 0 && elem.scrollLeft === 0) ||
            (event.deltaX > 0 && elem.offsetWidth + elem.scrollLeft >= elem.scrollWidth))
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a more efficient solution than recalculating the scroll in js, disabling the body scrolling when scrolling the child element.

HTML:

```
<div onmouseover="disableScroll();" onmouseout="enableScroll();">
    content
</div>
```

JS:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
function enableScroll() {
    body.style.overflowY = 'auto';
}
function disableScroll() {
    body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: This is perfect except I have some content that moves when the scrollbar disappears and the page gets wider.

Comment: If anyone else uses this solution and has the issue of right-aligned elements moving, I used `function enableScroll() {
  body.style.overflowY = 'auto';
  $('body').css({width:'100%'});
  $('body').css({float:'none'});

  
 }
 function disableScroll() {
  var bodyWidth = $("body").width();
  body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
  $('body').css({width:bodyWidth+'px'});
  $('body').css({float:'left'});

 }` to remedy it.